# syntax error in mysql partitioning query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, partitioning

I'm trying to partition a table. The partitioning is based on the gap_id and the profile_code. However I'm getting following error:

> Inconsistency in usage of column lists for partitioning near '),
>   ('S00') ),
>       PARTITION p1 VALUES IN ( (1), ('S01') ),
>       PARTITION p2 VALU' at line 8

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, someone's who's got a tip for me?

```
    CREATE TABLE test_partitioning (
    gap_id INT,
    profile_code VARCHAR(25),
    val INT,
    date_timestamp DATE
)

    PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(gap_id,profile_code) (
        PARTITION p0 VALUES IN ( (1), ('S00') ),
        PARTITION p1 VALUES IN ( (1), ('S01') ),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES IN ( (2), ('S00') ),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES IN ( (2), ('S01') )
    );
```

Comment: What do you hope to gain by partitioning?  I doubt if this table will perform any better than a non-partitioned table with suitable indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each tuple in the list have the same number of columns as the list of partition columns:

```
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(gap_id,profile_code) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES IN ( (1, 'S00') ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN ( (1, 'S01') ),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES IN ( (2, 'S00') ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES IN ( (2, 'S01') )
);
```